# Is there a way to programatically manipulate a shortcut title

Tags: swift, beta, ios12

[image]
I know we can pass parameters to the title but I am wondering if I can set the full title programmatically when donating the intent. Mostly because I need to handle some grammar rules for English and French.

Thanks

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but apparently there is a WWDC2018 presentation on the localisation workflows for Xcode 10 which include intents - [linked via New Localization Workflows in Xcode 10
WWDC 2018](https://medium.com/@nilotic2/new-localization-workflows-in-xcode-10-8c92c3f9c86e)

Comment: I watched... it has some samples on how to manage pluralization, but in my case, I need some info on how to handle possessive nouns (like Chris' cat or Mark's Cat)... maybe is the same process but I did not understand how to do it from the vide. Thanks anyways